# Any way to use & in \label{}

Tags: symbols

see question in title.
The title of the picture has to include a "R&D" . How can i make this work?
Thank you for your help
Paul

Comment: Do you really mean `\label{}`? If yes we need a minimal working example because `\label{R&G}` (and `\ref{R&G}`) works just fine unless maybe you're using some package which redefines `\label`… I'm guessing you rather mean `\caption{}`? Then you probably want `\&`: `\caption{R\&G}`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.